# Soup.find_all returning an empty list

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a player stats table for NBA stats using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, but the response I am getting is not same as what I see using "Inspect Element"

The `div` containing this table is has class attribute: `class="nba-stat-table__overflow`. However, whenever I run the following code I get an empty list:

```py
table = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class="nba-stat-table__overflow'})
```

Here is my full code:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/players/boxscores/?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class="nba-stat-table__overflow'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the page is load via `JavaScript`, So `bs4` or `requests` modules will not be able to render the `JavaScript` on the fly.

You should use `selenium` or `requests_html` modules to render the `JS`, But i noticed that the website is using `API`, which can be used to fetch the data, So I've called it and extracted the data.

Check My previous [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044616/using-find-all-function-returns-an-unexpected-result-set/61045691#61045691) which explain for you how to fetch the `API`.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = {
    "Counter": "1000",
    "DateFrom": "",
    "DateTo": "",
    "Direction": "DESC",
    "LeagueID": "00",
    "PlayerOrTeam": "P",
    "Season": "2018-19",
    "SeasonType": "Regular Season",
    "Sorter": "DATE"
}


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0',
    "x-nba-stats-origin": "stats",
    "x-nba-stats-token": "true",
    "Referer": "https://stats.nba.com/players/boxscores/?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season"
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
    goal = []
    for item in r['resultSets']:
        df = pd.DataFrame(item['rowSet'], columns=item['headers'])
        goal.append(df)

    new = pd.concat(goal)
    print(new)
    new.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguegamelog")
```

Output: [View-Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/29dfd6b4e43fa6e2e1c2bad4c2410f55/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution Ahmed, but can you explain me why my code was not working? Also how your code works? Can you share a link where I can learn more scraping?

Comment: Please explain to me why I was getting an empty list? Because I have watched a lot of video tutorials on scraping and did exactly the same thing but got an empty list even when i was scraping rottentomatoes.com

Comment: @ShantanuBisht answer updated. if my answer helps you, feel free to [accept and upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/734454) if you liked.

Comment: @Ahmed thanks a lot and sorry for bugging you with questions but can you tell me how to know if the website is loaded via javascript and using API?

Comment: @ShantanuBisht you welcome, read that answer and you will understand [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044616/using-find-all-function-returns-an-unexpected-result-set/61045691#61045691)