# How to scrape United States Oil fund holdings?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape the portfolio holdings for the USO fund here: http://www.uscfinvestments.com/holdings/uso

So far I could only get as far as this:

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.uscfinvestments.com/holdings/uso")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('div', id = 'holdingsTableWrapper')
```

Then I basically get nothing:

```
    [<div id="holdingsTableWrapper">
 <div id="portfolioTableDiv"></div>
 </div>, <div id="holdingsTableWrapper">
 <div id="holdingsTableDiv"></div>
 </div>]
```

Anyone know how to work around this?

EDIT:

I'm trying to scrape the contents of these tables:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `API` directly because the site is loaded via `JavaScript`. By using the `XHR` request.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("http://www.uscfinvestments.com/uscfinvestments-template/assets/charts/portfolioHoldings-uso.json").drop(0).drop(columns=['asofdate'])

print(df)
```

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("http://www.uscfinvestments.com/uscfinvestments-template/assets/charts/portfolioHoldings-uso.json").drop(0).drop(columns=['asofdate'])

print(df)
```

[image]

> Note: you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61045691/7658985) to understand how to get the `XHR` call.