# How can I scrape a phone number inside the span tag using python bs4 or any other lib

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: the html code page image]

I used bs4 methods

here is a link to an item on the website [haraj](https://haraj.com.sa/1179072070/%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9_%D9%81%D9%84%D9%87_%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC_%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87_%D9%85%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D9%87/)

```py
soup.select_one('.postWrapper .postMain .details .post_body .post_extra_info .contact a')
```

and

```py
soup.find('span', {'class', 'contact'})
```

but it wouldn't get it
any help is appreciated
thanks

Comment: Please, don't paste the `HTML` markup as an image, just post it as a `CODE`, please check [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to communicate with the `API` directly, since the page is rendered via `JavaScript` where it's call the backend `API` in order to fetch the content.

```py
import requests


# https://haraj.com.sa/1179070147

def main(url):
    params = {
        'queryName': 'postLikeInfo,postContact',
        'token': '',
        'clientid': '812f41b2-9936-4405-aa9c-378db19b8cc4',
        'version': '8.2.9 , 10 18 - 7 - 21'
    }
    data = {
        "query": "query postLikeInfo_postContact($id: Int!, $token: String,$postId: Int!) {\n\t\t\n\t\tpostLikeInfo(id: $id, token: $token)\n\t\t{ \n                    isLike\n                    total\n                    isFollowing\n                     }\n\t\n\r\n\t\tpostContact(postId: $postId)\n\t\t{ \n                    contactText\n                    contactMobile\n                     }\n\t\n\t}",
        "variables": {
            "id": 79070147,
            "postId": 79070147,
            "token": ""
        }
    }
    r = requests.post(url, params=params, json=data)
    print(r.json()['data']['postContact']['contactMobile'])


main('https://graphql.haraj.com.sa/')
```

Output:

```
+966536010587
```

Also in order to parse the full Ads, follow the below call:

```py
import requests


# https://haraj.com.sa/1179070147

def main(url):
    params = {
        'queryName': 'detailsPosts_singlePost',
        'token': '',
        'clientid': '812f41b2-9936-4405-aa9c-378db19b8cc4',
        'version': '8.2.9 , 10 18 - 7 - 21'
    }
    data = {
        "query": "query($ids:[Int]) { posts( id:$ids) {\n\t\titems {\n\t\t\tid status authorUsername title city postDate updateDate hasImage thumbURL authorId bodyHTML bodyTEXT city tags imagesList commentStatus commentCount upRank downRank geoHash\n\t\t}\n\t\tpageInfo {\n\t\t\thasNextPage\n\t\t}\n\t\t} }",
        "variables": {
            "ids": [
                79070147
            ]
        }
    }
    r = requests.post(url, params=params, json=data)
    print(r.json())


main('https://graphql.haraj.com.sa/')
```

Output:

```
{
   "data":{
      "posts":{
         "items":[
            {
               "id":79070147,
               "status":true,
               "authorUsername":"mostafa awd",
               "title":"فيلا للبيع في حي شبرا في الرياض",
               "city":"الرياض",
               "postDate":1627937386,
               "updateDate":1627937386,
               "hasImage":true,
               "thumbURL":"536010587_1627936555504.jpg",
               "authorId":12799016,
               "bodyHTML":" السعر : 700,000 ريال\n            <p>فيلا للبيع في حي شبرا ، الرياض ، الرياض</p>\n<p>الواجهة شرق</p><p>3 غرف نوم</p><p>صالتان</p><p>5 دورات مياة</p><p>عرض الشارع 20 متر</p><p>درج صالة</p><p>غرفة خادمة</p><p>بيت شعر</p><p>حوش</p><p>مطبخ</p><p>ملحق</p><p>مدخل سيارة</p><p>دوبلكس</p><p>المساحة 250 متر مربع</p>\n<p><img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555504.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555547.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555596.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555661.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555716.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555770.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555832.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555889.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555951.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556015.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556070.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556128.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556191.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556256.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556336.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556411.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556483.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556555.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556632.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556709.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" >\n<img src=\"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556791.jpg\"  loading=\"lazy\" ></p>",
               "bodyTEXT":"السعر : 700,000 ريال\n             \nفيلا للبيع في حي شبرا ، الرياض ، الرياض\n \nالواجهة شرق \n3 غرف نوم \nصالتان \n5 دورات مياة \nعرض الشارع 20 متر \nدرج صالة \nغرفة خادمة \nبيت شعر \nحوش \nمطبخ \nملحق \nمدخل سيارة \nدوبلكس \nالمساحة 250 متر مربع",
               "tags":[
                  "حراج العقار",
                  "عقار حي شبرا في الرياض",
                  "فلل للبيع",
                  "فلل للبيع في الرياض",
                  "فلل للبيع في حي شبرا في الرياض"
               ],
               "imagesList":[
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555504.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555547.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555596.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555661.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555716.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555770.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555832.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555889.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936555951.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556015.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556070.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556128.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556191.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556256.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556336.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556411.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556483.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556555.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556632.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556709.jpg",
                  "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aqar/props/536010587_1627936556791.jpg"
               ],
               "commentStatus":1,
               "commentCount":0,
               "upRank":0,
               "downRank":0,
               "geoHash":"th35vce06"
            }
         ],
         "pageInfo":{
            "hasNextPage":false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It returns an empty list

Comment: @OmarMahmnoud then you are dealing with `JS` website, may you share the url ?

Comment: Sure 
here 
[the url](https://haraj.com.sa/tags/%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1)

Comment: @OmarMahmnoud [edit] your question and include the url, also I'm unable to see any tag include `tel:` within the main page, seems you referring to the inner pages!

Comment: So sorry this my very first time asking a question here 
I added the url to the post 
and i see it now in this box 
some adds have text others have phone numbers 
here is the one in the picture 
[page](https://haraj.com.sa/1179070147/%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A7_%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9_%D9%81%D9%8A_%D8%AD%D9%8A_%D8%B4%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7_%D9%81%D9%8A_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B6/)

other pages have [this](https://haraj.com.sa/1179072070/%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9_%D9%81%D9%84%D9%87_%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC_%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87_%D9%85%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D9%87/) code .

Comment: You are a life-saver thank you so so much
I really appreciate the help
and if it's not too much to ask can you provide a bit of explaining to this cause 
i'm still learning python and that was kind of project to me, so i would like to get a better understanding 
again only if you feel like it
Thanks a million though

Comment: @OmarMahmnoud https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044616/using-find-all-function-returns-an-unexpected-result-set/61045691#61045691

Comment: One last question 
how do i get the post id ?
if i want to do this for all the posts in the main page
how can i get the ids for each post?

Comment: @OmarMahmnoud we are limited to provide an answer for the initial question being asked in order to maintain the community orders. Please open new thread for that.

Comment: terribly sorry, but new thread meaning new question ?

Comment: @OmarMahmnoud Yes.

Comment: I did it . Done

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use select and CSS selectors like .class, #id and tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content='''<div class="test1">
   <a href="www.google.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test2">
   <a href="www.stackoverflow.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test3">
   <a href="www.msn.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test4">
   <a href="www.naver.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test5">
   <a href="www.ios.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

all_a = soup.select('.test5 a')

for a in all_a:
    print(a['href'])
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: please can you take look at the image of the website
the tags has now classes and it's deep inside divs and spans